# TDD with IronPython

Tags: tdd, ironpython

Can anyone recommend tools or articles that help me to learn how to TDD IronPython code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of IronPython (v2.0) doesn't seem to agree with nose. This may have been fixed in 2.6, but I haven't re-run my test to figure that out yet. So for now you're only option - unless someone has experimented with one of the other python testing frameworks - pyunit is you're only choice.

You may also want to check out mock, a mocking framework created by Michael Foord which pretty much guarantees that it's going to work just fine with IronPython. If I recall correctly, he even shows some examples in his book, IronPython in Action.

Finally, you should probably check out [this link from the cheesecake project](http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) for several other tools that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 3):

IronPython has a good unit testing framework inherited from Python called PyUnit.

Writing unit tests using PyUnit is simple:

1. import unittest class
2. Create a class that inherits unittest.TestCase (test fixture)
3. Write test methods using assertions methods

You can read more about it in the following links:

- I wrote a blog post on the subject - [Getting started with IronPython – Part 3: unit testing](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2009/05/20/getting-started-with-ironpython-part-3-unit-testing.aspx). You can find relevant links at the bottom of the post.
- MetaDeveloper has a similar post - [Unit Tests with Iron Python](http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/03/unit-tests-with-iron-python.html)
- [unittest.py documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) - very good resource along with code snippets

If you use unittest.py consider using [nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/) as well, nose provides an alternate test discovery and running process for unittest. Should make writing and running unit tests easier.